# Android cutting my text when using fragments

Tags: android, scrollview, fragment

I have an activity with one fragment. On top of the fragment, I want to place and small advertisement. The problem is, if I define anything on top of my fragment, the text inside my frag will appear cutted. Look at the images (before showing the advertisement and after).

Before: [image: Normal image]
After: [image: Problematic image]
Note the scrollbar, it's on the top, which means it's cutting the visibility of my button.

All I wanted was to keep the text 'Jogar' visible when the advertisement is visible.
Here is some of the xml and code to help, if necessary.
Please, help me if you have any idea how to fix it.

activity_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00F">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adUnitId="..."
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0F0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/play"
            style="@style/TextFont"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/rankButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rank"
            style="@style/TextFont"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/achievementsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/achievements"
            style="@style/TextFont" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            style="@style/TextFont"/>
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
            android:text="@string/logout"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

At the Fragment class, I inflate the view calling:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_initial, container, false);
    ...
```

At the Activity class, I call the fragment with:

```
fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
    initialMenu = new InitialMenu();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, initialMenu, "initialFrag").commit();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you place the banner ad in the Fragment's xml layout, above the ScrollView?

Comment: Because it would lose the purpose of using fragments. It would be the same as I was doing before, using only Activities. I have to show the same banner in several screens.

Comment: Try to remove the `android:layout_gravity="center"` property from the the `LinearLayout` that is wrapped by the `ScrollView` in the fragment layout. That property doesn't make sense and could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog you solved it. Now it works. Post it as an answer and I'll give you the points you deserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the `android:layout_gravity="center"` property from the the `LinearLayout` that is wrapped by the `ScrollView` in the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:gravity="center">
//...
```

That property doesn't make sense as you tell the `Linearlayout` to center itself in a parent that gives it as much space as it needs/wants(and using that property seems for some reasons to offset the content of the `ScrollView`).

Comment: Give This Guy a Nobel in Android

Answer (score 0):

Consider this solution - use RelativeLayout instead of linear and place fragment below adView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00F">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adUnitId="a151a1ce3f32101"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, CF4058453805477305A64DACC4D23425"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"            
        anroid:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        android:background="#0F0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your `FrameLayout` you have the height set to `match_parent` so it will match the height of the device, thus going behind your `AdView`. Try switching this to `wrap_content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00F">
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:adUnitId="..."
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0F0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why would the `FrameLayout` extend to full screen when it's declared as the second child of a vertical `LinearLayout`?

Comment: The FrameLayout's height set to match_parent shouldn't match the height of my device, but the remaining height available after AdView inflates. I tried to change it to wrap_content, but didn't have any change, as expected.